# how to show multiple category name from checkbox value in eloquent relationship laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

firstly, i'm a newbie in laravel.

i insert a array data as a string in server.
column name "category_id" & value like "1,2,3,4".

Now i just want to show these id's category name with eloquent relationship.
Using laravel latest version.

view page

```
{{$category_var = explode(',',$post->category_id)}}

@foreach($category_var as $category)
    @if($category)
       <span class="badge mb-3"><a href="#" class="text-white">{{$post->category->category}}</a> </span>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

class page

```
public function category(){
      return $this-> belongsTo(Category::class);
  }
```

Controller page

```
public function index()
    {
        $posts = post::paginate(9);
        return view('pages/home',compact('posts'));
    }
```

anything else need just ask me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just use the benefits of models and relation like below:

```php
@foreach($posts as $post)
    @foreach($post->category as $category)
        <span class="badge mb-3">
            <a href="#" class="text-white">{{ $category->(what ever you want from category model) }}</a> 
        </span>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: i got a error - Trying to get property 'category' of non-object. Any suggestions                                                                                                         `@foreach($posts as $post)
    @foreach($post->category as $category)
        <span class="badge mb-3">
            <a href="#" class="text-white">{{ $category->category->category }}</a> 
        </span>
    @endforeach
@endforeach`

Comment: what is ```$category->category->category```? , try to see whats $category with {{ dd($category)  }}, then use the proper attribute

Comment: `$category->category->category` it's just show me result for the last id name. i wanted all after your suggestions it's say that category is non-object.{{ dd($category) }} after use show me just 'true'. you can do with anydesk

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't. sorry, after debugging your code, you can do it well, wish you luck

Comment: yeah i appreciate. & thnx for your suggestions.